# Show FULL Columns only specific columns of table

Tags: mysql, sql

Show FULL Columns docs is  http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html.
When i try

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM projects
```

it return all columns info, but i want to get only `id` column info. I tried this codes:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS id FROM projects;
SHOW FULL COLUMNS.id FROM projects;
SHOW FULL COLUMNS|id FROM projects;
```

but all time i get this

> Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id FROM projects' at line 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `WHERE` clause, try this:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM projects WHERE Field='id';
```

You can add multiple columns as such:

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM projects WHERE Field IN ('id', 'name');
```

Comment: can you help if i wont `id` and `name` column info get

Comment: I try this `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM projects WHERE FIELD IN 'id', 'name';`

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use the INFORMATION_SCHEMA if you want more control over the information you query.

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='projects' AND COLUMN_NAME='id';
```

Comment: It is also return other table info

Comment: You have control over the columns returned. You don't have to use `SELECT *`.